# Exception System.AppDomainUnloadedException when opening an oracle connection in unit test

Tags: c#, oracle, unit-testing, mstest

When running this unit test:

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTest1 {
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1 {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1() {
            string conString = "...";

            var Connection = new OracleConnection(conString);
            Connection.Open();
            Connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following message in the Output Window:

> System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded
>   AppDomain. This can happen if the test(s) started a thread but did not
>   stop it. Make sure that all the threads started by the test(s) are
>   stopped before completion.

If I debug the test, I see the following in the Output Window (my OS language is German):

> System.Transactions Critical: 0 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/UnhandledUnbehandelte
>   Ausnahmevstest.executionengine.x86.exeSystem.AppDomainUnloadedException,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089Es wurde
>   versucht, auf eine entladene Anwendungsdomäne
>   zuzugreifen.
>   System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Es
>   wurde versucht, auf eine entladene Anwendungsdomäne
>   zuzugreifen.

Seems that the error happens after the ClassCleanup in the test.

I understand that during the end of the test "something" that is unloaded is tried to be accessed. That should have to do somehow with the Oracle connection.

OracleConnection itself does not implement IDisposable. There should be no need to use the using construct or calling its Dispose() method (I tried just in case).

I am a bit clueless at the moment, I could use some hints. Thank you!

Comment: `System.Transactions` that means you used a TransactionScope somewhere, in a test setup method perhaps? Have you *closed* the transaction? This isn't specific to Oracle, you'd get the same error with any other database. Please post the full test code.

Comment: Hint: Don't use localized versions of .NET, that disables the best tool of finding answers - googling for the error message

Comment: Any chance that the error message is actually correct? The message means that a test started on one thread and left alive even after the test ended *and the test dll was unloaded* by the test runner.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: No, I didn't (explicitly) open any transaction. This is my full code. Debugging shows that the private property m_oraTransaction of the Connection object is null. I am currently searching why possibly is the test left alive. This seems to be the problem.

Comment: Did you by any chance found a definitive answer to this thread @Manolis?